# stringWithCString deprecated... so what do i use with char* returned by sysctlbyname?

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, nsstring

I know how to handle this when changing `stringWithCString` in SQLite... you just `stringWithUTF8String` instead.  Is this the same with a `char *` when it is returned by `sysctlbyname`?  (see code below)

```
- (NSString *) platform{
    size_t size;
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
    char *machine = malloc(size);
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", machine, &size, NULL, 0);
    NSString *platform = [NSString stringWithCString:machine];
    free(machine);
    return platform;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: yes, stringWithUTF8String returns character string.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If the C string you're using is UTF-8-encoded, then use `stringWithUTF8String:`.  If it's plain ASCII, then use `stringWithCString:encoding:` with an encoding of `NSASCIIStringEncoding`.  Otherwise, it's probably encoded using Latin-1, in which case you should use `stringWithCString:encoding:` with an encoding of `NSISOLatin1StringEncoding`.

In this case, `sysctlbyname` is almost certainly going to give you back an ASCII string, so you should do this:

```
NSString *platform = [NSString stringWithCString:machine encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Though using either of the other two methods will do you no harm.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to specify the string encoding, which is ASCII in the case of sysctlbyname:

```
NSString *platform = [NSString stringWithCString:machine encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 1):

stringWithCString: is deprecated in favour of stringWithCString:encoding:. You could use [NSString defaultCStringEncoding] to exactly reproduce the behaviour of stringWithCString: but you're probably better off specifying NSASCIIStringEncoding or NSUTF8StringEncoding. The encoding returned by sysctlbyname seems to be implicit, so 7-bit ASCII is a safe bet, making either encoding suitable.

Answer (score 1):

If you find error in

```
errorString = [NSString stringWithCString:iax_errstr];
```

try this

```
errorString = [NSString stringWithCString:iax_errstr encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]
```